# Does the expression "rad excuse" exist?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions, american-english

In the musical "Be More Chill", one of the characters, at 1:10, says the following:

> 'cause a Halloween party is a rad excuse to put our bodies through mad abuse... ([source](https://youtu.be/0xaLCvBYjrQ?t=67))

Do Americans use this expression often?

Answer (score 3):

"Rad" is a slang word meaning roughly the same as slang words like "cool", "awesome", etc, that is "extremely exciting or good". Mainly used by teenagers. The fact that it is in the Cambridge Dictionary probably means that it is now very old-fashioned. Probably derived from "radical".

> a rad new computer game

[Rad (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rad)